# Retrieve Value After A Specfic Character SQL

Tags: sql

I have a field in a table that has data that looks like the following

```
FieldA
CO-Complete
AB-anotherOne
CD-duffle
XY-monkey was here
```

How do I use SQL to return the entire string after the hyphen (-) ?

I am using SQL Server

Comment: which database are you using?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select SUBSTRING(test1.val, charindex('-', test1.val,0)+1, len(test1.val))
from test1
```

Answer (score 0):

In [standard SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), there is a `POSITION('-' IN value)` and `SUBSTRING(value FROM pos)`. For example MySQL supports it.